# How do i make it so that i can upload multiple files into form control

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

currently i managed to upload 1 file which is a jpeg and it works.
but now im trying to work on the code to be able to upload 3 files at once but all im getting is the first picture i selected using the file upload function. am i doing something wrong?
This is my component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.surveyForm = this.fb.group({
      ques1: '',
      selectedOpt: '',
      pic1: '',
      pic2: '',
      pic3: ''
    });
  }

  // for uploading images
  getData(file: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    });
  }

  getPic2(file: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    });
  }

  getPic3(file: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const customFile = document.getElementById("customFile")!;
    const files = customFile as HTMLInputElement
    const file = files!.files![0]
    this.getData(file),this.getPic2(file),this.getPic3(file).then(data => {
      this.surveyForm.value.pic1 = data
      this.surveyForm.value.pic2 = data
      this.surveyForm.value.pic3 = data
      this.userService.addSurveyRes(
        this.surveyForm.value.ques1,
        this.surveyForm.value.selectedOpt,
        this.surveyForm.value.pic1,
        this.surveyForm.value.pic2,
        this.surveyForm.value.pic3).subscribe(results => {
          alert("Thank you for your response.");
          location.reload();
        });
    })
  }
```

Comment: can you not just set your input to multiple? <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple>

Comment: In your `onSubmit` function you're setting `const file = files!.files![0]`, so file will always be the first image. The functions `getData,getPic1,getPic2` are all the same and you call each of them with the same input. You need to iterate over all uploaded files

Comment: @mrJQuery hello i think i misunderstood your comment. what do you mean by iterate over all uploaded files?

Comment: files!.files![0] returns the first uploaded file, files!.files![1] the second one and so on. look up how to iterate over a `FileList` and asign each value to your formControl